# Why I can not at font into my table?

Tags: css, fonts

I am trying to change the font in my `Job Information` table, but it doesn't work I try to search google and youtube but I still can not.who can help me please !!
My code is as follows:

```
#content-area-job-details #site-content-job-details .entry-content table.job-table tbody {
  font-family: Arial,Khmer !important;
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: It's very importain to spell important correctly, then you won't have so many problames. Spellcheck is your friend.

Comment: I cahng it too but still not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use commas between the css selectors. And as the other people say, important was spelled wrongly. Furthermore, as radiation said, no `<tbody>` tag is present in your page or table, therefore nothing is selected by the css. Additionally remove the Khmer part from the font-family, as it might not be recognized.

```
#content-area-job-details, #site-content-job-details, .entry-content, table.job-table tbody{
     font-family: Arial,Khmer !important;
}
```

If Khmer is a custom font, have you included it in your website? As a font installed on your local PC will not automatic work on the internet.

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/q6z5wmp8/

Comment: Can u edit ur answer bro ?

Comment: You're right about the commas between selectors. But, the `tbody` element actually does not need a start tag to be present in a table. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3dLv2h9f/) for an example. There is a `tbody`!

Comment: Indeed, but gives Nice readability haha. And you can use it to style your table

Answer (score -1):

You have a misprint in `!importain` and you are targeting a wrong dom element.

```
.job_info {
    font-family: Arial, Khmer !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is `!important` not  `!importain`

```
font-family: arial,Khmer !important;
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no `<tbody>` tag in your page.

Comment: Yes but it still not work

Comment: #content-area-job-details #site-content-job-details .entry-content table.job-table{
  font-family: Arial,Khmer !importain;
}

Comment: @Perrykipkerrie has the correct answer below.  Your selector needs to have commas.

Comment: @Akarienta, it most certainly does answer the question.  This was not a critique or request for clarification.  It was an answer to why the selector was not working.

Comment: 5answer but no one can fix it

Comment: There is `tbody` as it is autosubstituted during page parsing.

Comment: @raduation Although this is realy bad question you should extend your answer and get OP more clarification. This is much more comment then answer because of its length and quality.

Comment: ok now I am ask a new question thaz bro

Answer (score -1):

first I am sorry for my mistake,I am very thank you for your helpfull  and now I can find the correct answer is:

#content-area-job-details, #site-content-job-details, .entry-content, table.job-table tbody pre