# Why is my selector not working in CSS or why I can not change the font in my table?

Tags: css

I have a problem in my CSS selector. I want to change my job information font, but I can't get it to work. I've tried multiple ways:

```
#content-area-job-details #site-content-job-details .entry-content table.job-table tbody {
    font-family: Arial,Khmer !important;
}
```

```
.job-table tbody {
    font-family: Arial,Khmer !important;
}
```

```
.job_info {
    font-family: Arial, Khmer !important;
}
```

```
.job-table {
    font-family: Arial, Khmer !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, please improve this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284604/why-i-can-not-assign-font-in-my-table-tbody You have already asked it there.

Comment: Ok I will improve it now

Comment: Can you help me ? answer please

Comment: Yes, we can help you if you either delete this thread or the other one. You can respond to numerous answers people have provided. They will fix the problem for you.

Comment: show your HTML code to refer.

Comment: Thank bro Now I can find my problame,

Comment: #content-area-job-details, #site-content-job-details, .entry-content, table.job-table tbody pre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your `<pre>` tag, or add style in your `<pre style="font-family:Arial,Khmer;">` this may solve your problem. But avoid using input style on your HTML tags or use `<ul><li>`

Comment: yes thz bro it work for me

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the tag `<pre>`. It overloads your font for your table.
Instead of using this tag pre, use the `<ul><li>` to make a list.

Comment: Ok I will try ur folow thz bro

Answer (score -1):

You gave the same font family to your body also. SO the current font-family for your "Job information" is already the font the font which you are trying to give here